# An error occurred (AccessDeniedException): Team is not associated to an AWS Account

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-honeycode

AWS Honeycode API service call from AWS Glue python code using boto3 is giving issue.

Sharing the code snippet below:

```
import boto3

honeycode_client = boto3.client('honeycode')
response = honeycode_client.list_tables(workbookId = 'eb59751e-ef06-4de0-a4a9-c355e49308cd')
```

NOTE: workbook and tables are already created in Honeycode.
Role applied to glue job is having below policies:

AmazonS3FullAccess

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

AmazonHoneycodeFullAccess

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "honeycode:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Above code snippet is giving below error:

**AccessDeniedException: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ListTables operation: Team is not associated to an AWS Account**

what extra access is required for above mentioned access issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Team is not associated to an AWS Account.** This message is very much clear that Honeycode team is not connected with AWS Account.

To connect Honeycode team with AWS account, Go to **Connect AWS account**, bottom right in Honeycode team's page and provide the AWS account ID(12-digit) and proceed.

After successful connection status will change(in sometime) as shown below.

[image]

After above successful steps, AWS Honeycode API service call from AWS Glue python code started working.